# How do you select nth row for each ID?

Tags: sql-server

How do you select all nth rows for each ID?
My table looks somewhat like this :

```
    ID  fName   data
     1  Hari    20
     1  Hari    30
     2  John    89
     2  John    38
     2  John    55
```

In this case, how do you select all 2nd rows for each ID?

The result would look like this :

```
    ID  fName   data
     1  Hari    30
     2  John    38
```

Comment: How do you order the table?

Comment: Which DB? Is it oracle

Comment: rows for each id are ordered by date field.

Comment: No, its Microsoft SqlServer2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will help in SQL SERVER 2012:

```
SELECT ID,  FNAME,   DATA FROM 
(
     SELECT TEST_DATA.*, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ORDER_BY_CONDITION) AS RANK
     FROM TEST_DATA
) T 
WHERE T.RANK=2
```

Change your order by condition(ORDER_BY_CONDITION accordingly

Fiddle for SQL SERVER 2012 here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f59a1/3

**EDIT:**  For multiple tables, you can try with CTE as in the fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a5b1d/10

Comment: Now how do i implement it on sql server? I don't have any experience with oracle. Anyways thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user3694016: The above code is for SQLServer only. It will work. Just try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Checking the link now.

Comment: @user3694016: Yes please. If it helped you, accept as answer by clicking the grey tick mark next to this answer.

Comment: The rows above are from two different tables. How do i implement this with inner join? Still confused.

Comment: @user3694016: Refer my editted fiddle. Hope it helps

Comment: select * from 
 (
 select * , row_number() over (partition by transactions.MemberID order by transactions.UpdatedTill) as rank from transactions inner join members on members.ID = transactions.memberID
 ) t where t.rank=2  , it says : The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 't'.

Comment: If that error comes, then replace * with column names. Specify column names explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following query work for you? (Replace the `<tablename>` and the `<datecolumn>` names)

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM <tablename> tbl
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY <datecolumn>) rn
    FROM <tablename>
) row_numbers
ON tbl.ID = row_numbers.ID AND tbl.<datecolumn> = row_numbers.<datecolumn> AND row_numbers.rn = 2;
```

**Reference**:

[ROW_NUMBER function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: I'm already using Inner Join. The rows from the above tables are from two different tables. The first row for each ID is from table1 and all the other rows for that ID are from table2. I want a single row of columns from both tables for each ID. I'm not very experienced with sql. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`...

```
;
WITH    cteData ( ID, fName, data )
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        fName ,
                        data ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() 
                         OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateField ) AS 'rowNum' 
FROM tblName
             )
    SELECT  ID ,
            fName ,
            data
    FROM    cteData
    WHERE   rowNum = 2--Im assuming 2 from the data presented in question
```